# YUI: ensuring DOM elements and scripts are ready

Tags: javascript, dom, yui

1. If I put my inline script after the DOM elements it interacts with, should I still use YUI 3's [domready event](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/event/event-timing.html)?
   I haven't noticed any problems, and it *seems* like I can count on the browser loading the page sequentially.  (I already use `YUI().use('node', ...` to make sure the YUI functions I need have been loaded since the YUI script is a separate file.)
2. Is there a way to speed up the loading of widgets like YUI 2's calendar?
   I load the [appropriate script](http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.1/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.8.0r4/build/calendar/calendar-min.js) in `<head>` element of my page.  I use `YUI().use('yui2-calendar', ...` to make sure the Calendar widget is available.  Unfortunately, this causes a short but noticeable delay when I load my page with the calendar.  If I omit the `YUI().use('yui2-calendar', ...` code then it shows up without a noticeable delay - but I guess this could cause the Calendar to not show up at all if the YUI script doesn't load in time?
3. With regards to #2, is it possible to reduce the visual artifact of the calendar not being present and then showing up?
   I've made it slightly better by specifying a height and width for the parent div so that at least the space is already allocated => minimal shifting around when it does load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need domready if the code that accesses DOM elements comes after those elements in the markup.  This applies to DOM scripting in general, not just YUI.
2. yui2-calendar is not identical to yahooapis.com/2.8.0r4/build/calendar/calendar-min.js.  The former includes some wrapping code to sandbox the Calendar API and its dependencies in the YUI 3 instance environment.  If you're including the YUI 2 scripts in the <head> (which you arguably should place at the end of the <body>), you don't need to use yui2-calendar.  Doing so just loads the Calendar code twice.  Otherwise, to leverage YUI 3's dynamic async loading, you can remove the <script>s from the <head> and just use('yui2-calendar').  You can get the appearance of speeding up the time to render by including the yui2-* combo <script> in your markup after the yui-min.js seed file.  Note the Loader will always fetch the css file, so you don't need to include that in the markup.

   <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?3.1.0/build/yui/yui.js"></script>

   <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2in3.1/2.8.0/build/yui2-yahoo/yui2-yahoo.js&2in3.1/2.8.0/build/yui2-dom/yui2-dom.js&2in3.1/2.8.0/build/yui2-event/yui2-event.js&2in3.1/2.8.0/build/yui2-calendar/yui2-calendar.js"></script>
3. You can include the css and markup of a rendered Calendar on page load, then render into the markup container.  I don't think YUI 2 calendar has the notion of progressive enhancement of existing markup baked in, but I could be wrong.  It should clobber the static table markup with its generated markup and vivify the UI.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer Luke - it is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If it's after the said nodes in question, then you don't need `DOMContentLoaded` (or domready).